# How to change position of UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I need to change frame position of navigation bar before the view is visible. I do it in viewWillAppear method by accessing frame coordinates but it seems to not work. But when I place the code to viewDidAppear it works as expected. It seems to me like iOS perform some layout operations after viewWillAppear callback. Is there any other place where it could be working? I also tried didLayoutSubviews, willLayoutSubviews but these are not called each time the view controller is going to be visible...

Comment: try in the ´viewWillLayoutSubviews´ method good luck

Comment: not working with viewWillLayoutSubviews also :(

Comment: can you share the code that you are using and what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to subclass navigation bar and place the code into layoutSubviews method.